# Is There a Triangle Wave Function?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, geometry, sine-wave

in a `for`-loop with `%` to get a saw function, for example using a period of 5 printing 2 cycles would look like this:

```
for(auto i = 0; i < 5 * 2; ++i) cout << i % 5 << endl;
```

Results in:

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4

I want a function returns a triangle wave, so for some function `foo`:

```
for(auto i = 0; i < 5 * 2; ++i) cout << foo(i, 5) << endl;
```

Would result in:

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   1
>   0
>   0
>   1
>   2
>   1
>   0

Is there such a function, or do I need to come up with my own?

Comment: could look like `abs(((i + 2) % 5) - 2)` except it gives 0 1 2 2 1 0 1 2 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought we should at least post the correct answer here before this question is closed cause it is a duplicate.

[Eric Bainvile's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1073628/2642059) is the correct one.

```
int foo(const int position, const int period){return period - abs(position % (2 * period) - period);}
```

However this gives a triangle wave with a range from [0, `period`] and a frequency of `2 * period` and I want a range from [0, `period / 2`] and a cycle of `period`. This can be accomplished by just passing half of the period to `foo` or by adjusting the function:

```
int foo(const int position, const int period){return period / 2 - abs(position % period - period / 2);}
```

With such a simple function inlining seems preferable though so our final result will be:

```
for(auto position = 0; position < 5 * 2; ++position) cout << 5 / 2 - abs(position % 5 - 5 / 2) << endl;
```

Yielding the requested:

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   1
>   0
>   0
>   1
>   2
>   1
>   0

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a very similar question was answered here: [Is there a one-line function that generates a triangle wave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073606/is-there-a-one-line-function-that-generates-a-triangle-wave)

Taken from Noldorin answer:

**Triangular Wave**

```
y = abs((x++ % 6) - 3);
```

This gives a triangular wave of period 6, oscillating between 3 and 0.

Now put that in a function:

```
int foo(int inputPosition, int period, int amplitude)
{
    return abs((inputPosition % period) - amplitude);
}
```

Comment: Your function's a little wak there bro. It not only fails to take the input I specified in the question, it also fails to compile cause `x` isn't defined. In any event [Cyber](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2296458/cyber) did do a good job finding that duplicate.

Comment: Right, I just noticed that right before I read your comment. I edited it and should be fixed now.

Comment: Getting closer, It still doesn't match the signature specified in the question but it compiles now. (I know we can all imply what you should be doing in `foo`, but we also could have all followed [Cyber](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2296458/cyber)'s link and implied an `foo` from there. If you're going to use someone else's solution to answer this question, it seems like you should at least tailor their answer to the actual question.)

Comment: Sorry, I was already writing the answer when Cyber posted the link. I wasn't just taking it from him. You probably should have done a 2 second Google search before even asking the question. Because that's how long it took me to find that link on my own. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: I believe you are correct that I should have taken more time to research, my mistake. Anyway back to working on this answer; it's close to right, have a look at [Eric Bainville's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1073628/2642059) that's the one you want to copy.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to make your own:

```
// Assumes 0 <= i < n
int foo(int i, int n) {
    int ix = i % n;
    if ( ix < n/2 )
        return ix;
    else
        return n-1-ix;
}
```